# Помогите распрасить xml

Tags: python, xml, парсер

Помогите распарсить xml на python:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="dectusers-stats.xsl"?>
<stats time="831530">
    <radio>
        <count text="Calls In" name="calls-in" value="428"/>
        <count text="Calls Out" name="calls-out" value="2"/>
        <count text="Handover" name="handovers" value="2"/>
        <count text="Handover Failed" name="handovers-fail" value="1"/>
    </radio>
</stats>
```

Comment: День добрый. А в чём именно у вас проблема? Какую библиотеку для парсинга вы используете?

Comment: Использую библиотеку xml.etree.cElementTree, никак не могу добиться вывода вида: Calls in 428 calls-out 2 и тд

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример вывода нужных атрибутов из xml

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('input.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for child in root:
     for node in child:
         print(node.attrib['text'],node.attrib['value'])
```

Вывод

```
Calls In 428
Calls Out 2
Handover 2
Handover Failed 1
```

Comment: Спасибо все получилось